# Constructing a convex hull for Li2O/O2 reaction

Tags: density-functional-theory

I am trying to construct a convex hull for a battery cathode with the following reactions:

\begin{align}
2\ce{Li_2O} \leftrightarrow \ce{Li_2O_2 + 2Li^+} \tag{1} \\ 
2\ce{Li_2O} \leftrightarrow \ce{LiO_2 + 3Li^+} \tag{2}
\end{align}

and I am not sure how to get started. As in, should look at $\ce{Li_xO_2}$, $Li_2O_y$ possible structures individually? Do I need to consider all $Li_xO_y$ possible structures? Given that the reaction involves only delithiation (with no change in the number of oxygen atoms), should I consider it as one would an intercalation reaction and set the formation energy to the following equation?

$E_f(Li_xO_2) = E(Li_xO_2) - xE(LiO_2)-(1-x)E(O_2).\tag{3}$

Comment: +1 welcome to our new community and thank you for contributing your question here! We hope to see much more of you in the future !!! I've made some edits, and I'd like you to take a look at them and fix up the rest of your post in a similar way. Also, we strongly prefer for users not to use TeX in the titles.

Comment: Thanks so much @NikeDattani. I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but just came today to check how things are going? Did you figure out the answer? Are you still working on this? Let us know! By the way, can you please take a look at my edit and fix the rest of the question in the same way?